# Rewrite relative location in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, location

I have server with varnish(:80) + nginx (:8080).
Nginx is frontend for other apache webserver.

There are a lot of redirects on apache werbserver.
Redirects uses relative location eg:

```
header('Location: /en/')
```

So i get links like:

> http://example.com:8080/en/

I can't changes redirects on apache server. So i need to rewrite it on nginx.
What is best way to get redirect to http://example.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

If nginx is proxying apache, you won't be able to use a Location header as your did in apache. You'll need to use the `rewrite` directive in nginx. This article provides a good explanation of using rewrites in [apache and nginx](http://liangsun.org/posts/how-to-translate-apaches-rewriterule-into-nginxs-rewrite/).

You might also find the following article useful, given your are redirecting an nginx server which is sitting behind varnish.

http://danielmiessler.com/blog/handling-redirects-with-varnish-and-nginx